# Strange behavior for Android activities

Tags: android, duplicates, launch

I have strange behavior for my Android applications. For example, I have application with two activities: activity1 and activity2. And I open acitivity2 from activity1 by button. Also, I have next definitions in manifest file:

```
<activity
 android:name="activity1" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
 android:name="activity2"
 android:exported="false" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Issue:

1. Launch application from "desktop" and open activity2.

   - RESULT: acitivity2 on screen.
2. Press "Home" button on Android device and go to "all programs" "folder".
3. Launch application again.

   - RESULT: activity1 on screen.
   - EXPECTED: activity2 on screen.
4. Press "back" on Android device.

   - RESULT: acitivity2 from previous launch is shown.

If we are launching application from "desktop" in step #3 all works as expected.

Please, help. I don't understand what going on and where I'm wrong.

Comment: define: `from "desktop"`

Comment: Main screen, launcher, screen that we see when device was unlocked. Not a place/screen where all installed application are listed.